# KSQL queries with node JS

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, ksqldb

I need to write Ksql queries to fetch data from kafka topics, from my nodeJS application.
I searched but couldn't find any library to execute KSQL queries.

any help appreciated.

Comment: Found no library? https://www.npmjs.com/package/ksqldb-js Otherwise, use axios, node-fetch, etc to just use the REST API